# How to update “ngx-bootstrap” from ^2.0.5 to 3.3.0?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use `minMode` as `month` in **ngx-bootstrap** but it is taking a total date is there any problem with version?

[Here is an issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZTD2.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to update the ngx-bootstrap to 3.3.0

then in the terminal use the command

```
 npm i ngx-bootstrap@3.3.0 --save
```

Hope it works!